# Nothing happens when running go get github.com/astaxie/beego

Tags: go

*warning: noob question ahead* :-)

I was trying to run `go get github.com/astaxie/beego` but it does nothing. I have been running examples I picked up from the internet and I installed gotour successfully. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the output of the `go version`, `go env`, `go get -v github.com/astaxie/beego`, `dir $GOPATH/src/github.com`, and `dir $GOPATH/src/github.com/astaxie` commands?

Comment: Looks like this was resolved off the page somewhere, would be helpful if you could have documented this! Got the same behaviour on my install

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my setup was messed up. I purged everything and installed golang using this nifty script: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm. It takes care of everything. Thanks @peterSO for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't show anything, it doesn't mean nothing works. Try doing the same with '-v' flag

```
go get -v github.com/astaxie/beego
```

Besides, all your downloads will be saved (most probably) somewhere to your '~' directory ('~/go/src' in my case), not in your current terminal directory

Answer (score 0):

if on Ubuntu/Debian?, try the golang package for installing go. it seems to work for me quite well.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, `sudo apt install golang-go && go get -v github.com/rapidloop/rtop`, still no errors/messages, `echo $?` return 0. _go version go1.10.4 linux/amd64_.